# Using functional programming to map one array to another

Tags: swift

What functional programming-ish function (map, reduce, zip) can I use to replace the functionality of this `for` loop? (array have different objects but same number of elements)

```
@IBOutlet var imageViews: [UIImageView]!
photoURLs = ["http://...photo1...", "http://...photo2...", "http://...photo3..."]

for (index, photo) in photoURLs.enumerated() {
    imageViews[index].setImageFromString(string: photo.urlString)
}
```

UPDATE: Most of the comments / answers are appropriate for the first version of this question that I asked. Now, I modified it with my concrete case.

Regarding duplicate question: This question does not address combining two arrays, it refers to copying values from one array to another, exact same indexes, but also putting them through a custom method.

Comment: Btw, your example code is not valid `swift` `for`. And even you fix syntax it very likely will crash on that subscript assignment line.

Comment: Guys, I modified specifying that this is pseudocode. Also, the arrays are different in my concrete example. I need to get the elements from the first one and place them in the exact same position in the second.

Comment: Ok, is `array2` already filled with something?

Comment: So, you want to move **all elements** from `firstArray`, in **the same order** to `array2`? Then @Adolfo 's comment is what are you looking for.

Comment: @Adolfo - please post your comment as an answer. It is the *correct* answer!

Comment: Guys, Adolfo got it right, but that's because of my mistake. I also need to make call a function on the items. I will update my question.

Comment: @Grimxn Post as an answer! ;)

Comment: Didn't you said `array2`(aka `imageViews`) is empty? If you will try to call method using result of subscript of empty array you will have very bad time.

Comment: @Teodor Ciuraru can you post your actual code instead of pseudo code? including the function you want to call on the elements of your array

Comment: @Ocunidee it's here. I was stating that is is empty as in it doesn't already have any values on any positions, not that it is `nil`.

Comment: suppose you have 5 outlets for imageviews,then you have to first add those imageviews in one array manually, then you can use for (index, photo) in photoURLs.enumerated() {
    imageViews[index].setImageFromString(string: photo)
}

Comment: you code is not working at all. Why would you have an IBOutlet of an array of ImageViews? Also photo in your for loop is of type String, a string does not have a property called urlString and finally we still don't have the signature of your setImageFromString method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I interleave two arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951824/how-can-i-interleave-two-arrays)

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru, `imageViews[index]` where `imageViews == []` (even if it's not `nil`) will result in crash, so you will have a bad time.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru, also `zip`ping with empty array (like in accepted answer) will result in empty array. So if your `imageViews` is actually empty you're doing something wrong over there.

Comment: Guys. Sorry for the confusion. The `imageViews` array is NOT nil. @Laffen, this question is not a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru, **C'mon, i'm talking (it's like 5th comment) about empty (`[]`) array, and you keep talking about `nil`.** What does `nil` has to do with all of this?

Comment: Ok. Nvm. I wasn't pretty attentive because it isn't really my case. Sorry :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
zip(imageViews, photoURLs)
    .forEach { $0.setImageFromString(string: $1.urlString) }
```

For a detail example:

```
let views = ["View0", "View1", "View2"]
let urls = ["url0", "url1", "url2"]

zip(views, urls)
    .forEach { print("View: \($0), URL: \($1)") }

// Result: 
View: View0, URL: url0
View: View1, URL: url1
View: View2, URL: url2
```

Comment: This is a correct answer to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! And, Here is the reference from apple: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip.

Answer (score 3):

Supossing that both array shoud contain the same elements...

```
let array2 = firstArray
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for what I asked before. Thank you. But I found out that my problem is a little complex than this and I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I can't test my code, but could be something like...

```
self.imageViews = photoURLs.map()
{ 
    guard let data = NSData(contentsOf: $0), let image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
        return UIImageView(image: nil)
    }

    return UIImageView(image: image)
)
```

Assuming that photoURLs is a `URL` array.

Comment: Thanks, Adolfo. Really appreciate. You guys helped me fulfill my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

```
let flatMappedNumbers = firstArray.flatMap { $0 }
print(flatMappedNumbers)
```

Comment: Why use `flatMap` here?

Comment: it ignores nil.

Comment: What if OP needs his `nil`s kept?

Comment: let flatMappedNumbers =  firstArray.map { $0  }

Comment: you can use map function also

Comment: I know, but you used `flatMap` in the answer for some reason. I want to know why.

Comment: I thought you want to ignore nil tht's why

Comment: map return array of Optional values, what in most cases you don't need, flat map is preferable.

Comment: @BohdanSavych, wut? If i `map` over say `[Int]` with `Int -> Int` function I will magically get `[Int?]` or something?

Comment: @user28434 my bad, I mean map [Int?] -> [Int?], flat map [Int?] -> [Int].

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because I think it fits my original question. If you can please find a solution for this new version of it, I would be grateful.