# Use of unresolved identifier 'finalArray'?

Tags: arrays, swift, function

```
var firstArray = ["1.","2.","3.","4."]

var secondArray = ["a","b","c"]

func combineTheArrays(array1: [Any], array2: [Any]) -> [Any] {

    var finalArray = [Any]()

    let maxIndex = array1.count >= array2.count ? array1.count : array2.count;

    for i in 0...maxIndex{
        if (array1.count > i){
            finalArray.append(array1[i])
        }
        if (array2.count > i){
            finalArray.append(array2[i])
        }
    } }

combineTheArrays(array1: firstArray, array2: secondArray)

print(finalArray)
```

I am trying to take two arrays with different/similar types and have it work through the function and combine into one single array. The ideal result of this func is to print:

```
finalArray = ["1.", "a", "2.", "b", "3.", "c", "4."]
```

Comment: finalArray is a local variable in the function. There should also be a "missing return in a function" error ...

Comment: (Unrelated to your concrete problem, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951824/how-can-i-interleave-two-arrays for other approaches to achieve the same result.)

Comment: You can simplify this code a lot by just using `zip` and `flatmap`: `zip(array1, array2).flatMap{ [$0, $1] }`

Comment: @Alexander: That's why I linked to the other Q&A :)

Comment: @MartinR Heh, I guess I missed your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close! You just need to return `finalArray` at the end of your function definition, and then assign the result of the function call, so that you can then use it (such as in a `print` call):

```
let finalArray = combineTheArrays(array1: firstArray, array2: secondArray)

print(finalArray)
```

You should also use generics to ensure that you can handle any kind of elements, so long as their types are the same. Unlike returning `Any`, your result will be an array of the same type, which will be safer and easier to work with. Here is how I would improve this code:

```
func combineTheArrays<T>(array1: [T], array2: [T]) -> [T] {

    let maxIndex = max(array1.count, array2.count);

    var finalArray = [T]()
    finalArray.reserveCapacity(array1.count + array2.count)

    for i in 0..<maxIndex {
        if i < array1.count { finalArray.append(array1[i]) }
        if i < array2.count { finalArray.append(array2[i]) }
    }

    return finalArray
}

var firstArray = ["1.","2.","3.","4."]
var secondArray = ["a","b","c"]
let finalArray = combineTheArrays(array1: firstArray, array2: secondArray)

print(finalArray)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent about 2 hours in total trying different to see how I could get it to print. I have a question though if you could answer, why do I need to make finalArray a constant if I am already making it a variable in the function?

Comment: Because that variable in the function has absolutely nothing to do with the outside world. It's a local variable that exists only for the duration of the function's lifetime. It's created when the function is called, and it's destroyed when the function is done.

Comment: In other words, `let finalArray` being called `finalArray` is merely a coincidence, it has nothing to do with the `var finalArray` local variable of the function.