# Append character in alternative format

Tags: swift

I have two strings which I need to merge. But I have to merge like below format.

```
var a = "abc"
var b = "def"
```

I need to do like : `adbecf`.

Just an normal a+b with some condition I tried. But not able to solve. Any idea ?

update :

```
let stringA = "abc"
 let stringB = "def"


func mergeStrings(a: String, b: String) -> String {

    let val = zip(a,b).reduce("") { (result, arg1) in
    let (char1, char2) = arg1
    return result + "\(char1)\(char2)"
}
return val
}
```

Comment: "Just an normal a+b with some condition I tried" What conditions? What have you tried? What's the logic?

Comment: its not `abcdef`. Its bit differ `adbecf`

Comment: @Larme  removing last charater and append again to string

Comment: Related: [How can I interleave two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951824/how-can-i-interleave-two-arrays)

Comment: What if the strings have different length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = "abc"
let b = "def"
let c = zip(a,b).reduce("") { (result, arg1) in
    let (char1, char2) = arg1
    return result + "\(char1)\(char2)"
}
print(c)//adbecf
```

in short

```
let c = zip(a,b).reduce("") { $0 + "\($1.0)\($1.1)" }
print(c)
```

Using [zip(*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) with two unequal length strings will end with ignoring remaining strings.

```
let a = "12345"
let b = "67"
let c = zip(a,b).reduce("") { $0 + "\($1.0)\($1.1)" }
print(c)//"1627"--> 345 is ignored
```

To fix this use

```
if a.count > b.count {
    c = c + String(a[b.endIndex...])
} else if b.count > a.count {
    c = c + String(b[a.endIndex...])
}
print(c)//"1627345"
```

Comment: but my input was abc, def only

Comment: @SaiKumar Do you have var a = "abc"
var b = "def" or any other?

Comment: @SaiKumar where and how are you calling mergeStrings() ?

Comment: it will return from that method. I just needs to return correct string

Comment: @SaiKumar you are passing some other string to this method. Use print(mergeStrings(a:stringA,b:stringB))

Answer (score 1):

This code handles merging of equally length string and also unequally length strings either inside the loop of `a` is longer or at the end if `b` is longer

```
var out = ""
for (n, c) in a.enumerated() {
    out.append(c)
    if n < b.count {
        out.append(b[b.index(b.startIndex, offsetBy: n)])
    }
}
if b.count > a.count {
    out += b.suffix(a.count)
}
```

To ignore any trailing characters

```
var out = ""
for (n, c) in a.enumerated() {
    if n < b.count {
        out.append(c)
        out.append(b[b.index(b.startIndex, offsetBy: n)])
    }
}
```